# Is it possible to use multiple database in a single edmx

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am using a database "abc"and a edmx to work with the database tables. Now i want to add a new database "efg".  is it better to add a new edmx file for the second database "efg" or use single edmx for both database? how can i achieve this?

Comment: You should tag this question as entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only have a single database in each edmx file. You will have to create a new edmx file for the second database.